# PDO não executa consulta

Tags: php, pdo

Tenho um formulário que faz uma busca via PDO, só que quando eu executo, ele não me retorna nada.

```
$PDO = db_connect();

$busca = $_POST['usuario'];
$vbusca = "%".$busca."%";

$sql = 'SELECT nome, tipo, cor FROM livro AS t WHERE ';

var_dump($sql);
$stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$vbusca]);
$total = $stmt->rowCount();
```

Dei um `var_dump` na variável `$stmt` e está me retornando o seguinte:

> string(57) "SELECT nome, tipo, cor FROM livro AS t WHERE"
>   object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(57) "SELECT
>   nome, tipo, cor FROM livro AS t WHERE" }

Comment: Como esta feito a conexão com o banco? E não de um var_dump no `$sql` e sim no `$total`

Comment: string(57) "SELECT nome, tipo, cor FROM livro AS t WHERE" int(0)

Comment: Não faltou o campo recebendo o valor após o WHERE? `WHERE busca = ?`

Comment: Seu select esta errado, faltou a coluna e a condição no **WHERE**.

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti como eu posso fazer para buscar nas 3 colunas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa definir o campo que receberá o post de busca, logo após a cláusula `WHERE`. Irei por como exemplo uma busca pelo nome do livro.
Veja seu código completo, onde removi o seu campo `vbusca`, não necessário e adicionando a variável `$busca` que recebe o `$_POST` diretamente na nova variável `$params`. Para que você possa entender baseado em seu código no conteúdo da sua questão.

```
$PDO = db_connect();

$busca = $_POST['usuario'];
$params = array("%$busca%");

// Busca pelo nome do livro
$sql = 'SELECT nome, tipo, cor FROM livro WHERE nome LIKE ?';

var_dump($sql);


$stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);

$total = $stmt->rowCount();
```

Comment: Está me retornando assim agora string(70) "SELECT nome, tipo, cor FROM busca AS t WHERE livro LIKE ?" int(0)

Comment: Mas qual campo vc quer buscar? Por exemplo, se for buscar pelo nome do livro, teria que ser: `$sql = 'SELECT nome, tipo, cor FROM livro WHERE nome LIKE ?';`

Comment: Não tem como fazer para procurar em todas as colunas?

Comment: @TeresaSantos Primeiramente, você tem que dizer se isto solucionou o seu problema número 1. O problema que vc questionou. Se sim, maravilha! O próximo passo seria outra questão. Pois é uma nova dúvida que você nos apresenta. já respondendo de antemão. Sim, tem como buscar em todas as colunas, mas mudaria essa base simples do seu código. Então, uma outra pergunta deverá ser feita.